# Proving that the language is not recursive enumerable

Tags: decision-theory, decidability

L is defined as the following language :

{  $<M>$ | M is a TM and for all input w, in the computation M(w) there is a state q that is visited an infinite number of times }

I was asked to prove that the language is not recursive enumerable yet I can't seem to get the reduction right. Any help/clues or hints will be gladly accepted.
Thanks!

Comment: From my understanding of the question, the language is made up of Turing machines. And the Turing machines that are members of the language don't halt on any input. Recursively enumerable means there's a Turing machine that can enumerate the language. I'm thinking maybe the existence of such a Turing machine would lead to a contradiction because it would not be able to decide its own memebership in the language.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ColmBhandal, But how do I prove it formally? From which language would you suggest I reduce this problem to?

Comment: no problem. I just posted an answer to a related question which may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281677/to-prove-a-language-is-not-recursive/2384424#2384424

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language above defines the set of Turing machines which never halt on any input. Note, this is the same thing as visiting a state an infinite number of times, assuming that the number of states are finite- apply an infinite version of the pigeon hole principle.

So, if this language was recusively enumerable, there'd be a Turing machine to decide whether each of its members belonged or not. So we'd be able to compute whether a machine never halted on any input. But this is impossible, because then we'd be able to solve the halting problem. I'll explain why in the next paragraph.

The assumption is we have a machine that can decide when another machine never halts on any input. Now we want to build a machine that solves the halting problem: for any $M$ and $x$, we want to decided whether $M(x)$ halts. Well, we can easily define a computer $C$ which ignores its input and just runs $M(x)$ every time $C(y) = M(x)$. Now we know that $C(y)$, because it ignores its input, either always halts for all inputs $y$ or never halts for any of them. But by our assumption we have a machine that decides whether $C$ never halts. The answer we get from this will give us the answer to $M(x)$ and solve the halting problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!